# Flow lookup Account Files

Tags: community, lightning-experience, visual-workflow

I have a screen in a Flow which I am trying to add a lookup component to but I can't seem to figure out how to configure it.
I want the lookup to allow users to find files attached to the account.

Files are ContentDocument in the API and they have the ContentDocumentLink that Links account and ContentDocument. They have the relationship name 'ContentDocumentLinks' and the field pointing to the account is 'LinkedEntityId'

How can I setup the lookup component to achieve that?

[image: Lookup Component Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you can't do it with a Lookup.. But I managed to achieve a similar result using a picklist instead and combining a Get Record with Record Choice Set to populate the files that exists inside a picklist.